# Using numpy to enter noise into data

Tags: gaussian, noise

I am new to data science and have to generate 200 numbers from a uniform distribution
set this as x and generate y data using x and injecting noise from the gaussian distribution
  y = 12x-4 + noise

**My Approach:** 
x = numpy.random.rand(200) --> This will generate 200 numbers form a uniform distribution
I am not sure hot to inject noise from the guassian distribution
probably it's like z = numpy.random.randn(200)
and y = 12 * x - 4 + z 
Is that a correct way to inject noise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `numpy.random.randn(n)` will generate an array of random numbers (generated by the normal distribution centered at 0) of size n. So just do:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(200)
y = 12 * x - 4 + np.random.rand(200)
```

Just as you put in your question.